# Sojourn times distribution in continous time Markov chains

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Hi everyone I'm trying to prove the following theorem about continous time, finite Markov's chains:

Let $J=\min\left\{t:X_{t}\neq i\right\}$. Under the law $\mathbb{P}_{i}$ of the Markov chain started in $X_{0}=i$ the random variables $J$ and $X(J)$ are independent. The distribution of $J$ is exponential with rate $q_{i}:=\sum_{j\neq i}q_{ij}$, i.e.
$$\forall t>0;\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\mathbb{P}_{i}\left\{J>t\right\}=e^{-q_{i}t}.$$
Moreover,
$$\mathbb{P}_{i}\left\{X(J)=j\right\}=\frac{q_{ij}}{q_{i}}$$.

The probability law $\mathbb{P}_{i}$ used in the theorem is simply defined in the following way:
$$\forall\,A\in\mathcal{F};\,\,\,\,\,\,\mathbb{P}_{i}\left\{A\right\}:=\mathbb{P}\left\{A|X(0)=i\right\}.$$

What one could observe is that every Markov's process of this form can be considered a Poisson process by simply considering a one to one function between the state set $I$ and the natural numbers, so every state is the number of occurences. But how can I prove that the sojourn time in the first state is exponentially distributed and how can the rate be exactly $q_{i}$?

Comment: The property in question is how I would *define* a continuous time Markov chain (CTMC): The time to leave a state $i$ is independent of the past and exponentially distributed with some rate $v_i$, once we leave we independently go to a new state $j$ with probability $P_{ij}$ (where $v_i$ is the sum of outgoing transition rates and  $P_{ij}=q_{ij}/v_i$). What is your starting point definition from which you want to prove that property?

Comment: The way I define a CTMC is a family of descrete random variables with a continous index set (time). For me the rate $v_{i}$ that you mentioned is the first derivative in 0 of the transition probability. I can leave a link of a pdf where this theorem is mentioned if you want to check it out: https://people.bath.ac.uk/maspm/Prob2B-Part2.pdf